# Silex shared service seems to be instantiated more than once

Tags: silex

I'm completely new to pretty much everything that has to do with websites (like HTML, PHP, Twig, Symfony, ...). And I have to set up a website from scratch with Silex.
So far I managed to get everything working, but I'm really lost with a shared service that I want to use. The information I set in one controller is not available in another one. I created a very small example to illustrate my problem:

```
//This is the main file app.php
<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/src/Inpainter.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->register(new Silex\Provider\TwigServiceProvider(), array(
    'twig.path' => __DIR__.'/templates',
));

$app['inpainter'] = $app->share(function() use($app) {
    return new Inpainter();
});

$app->get('/test/', function() use ($app){
    $app['inpainter']->setMask('foo');
    return $app['twig']->render('index.html.twig', array(
    ));
})
->bind('home');

$app->get('/downloads/', function() use ($app){
    $app['inpainter']->writeMask();
    return $app['twig']->render('downloads.html.twig', array(
    ));
})
->bind('downloads');

$app->run();

?>
```

The `index.html.twig` file just contains a link that redirects to 'downloads'.
The `Inpainter` class looks as follows:

```
<?php

class Inpainter {

    private $mask;

    public function setMask ($mask) {
        $this->mask = $mask;
    }

    public function writeMask() {
        echo 'I am inpainting with ' . $this->mask;
    }

}

?>
```

Now if I click on the link on the `index` site, the `downloads` site should display "I am inpainting with foo". But instead I have "I am inpainting with ". I'm pretty sure I have made a very stupid mistake, but I just can't find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is working as expected ... 8-)

If you are using a **link** in `index.html.twig` your application will be forced to create a new instance - so `$app['inpainter']->setMask()` was never called when executing the route `/downloads/`.

If you want to switch from one route (`/test/`) to another (`/downloads/`) and keeping your application instance alive, you can [use a subrequest](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/sub_requests.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

$app->get('/test/', function() use ($app){
  $app['inpainter']->setMask('foo');
  $subRequest = Request::create('/downloads/', 'GET');
  return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
})
->bind('home');
```

If you want to use the link within your template you must append an parameter to it or use a session to pass-through variables between the application instances.